# How can I make a table like the type in this image in LaTeX?

Tags: tables, booktabs

I'm trying to make a table like the one in following image in LaTeX

[image]

but I'm unsure how to go about it. I've been using the tabular environment from the `booktabs` package, but the following code doesn't produce the table correctly. There are breaks in the lines, the lines extend too far, etc.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ccc|ccccccc}
&&&&&\multicolumn{5}{c}{Capacity j} \\
&&i&0&1&2&3&4&5&6\\
\midrule
&&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
$w_1 = 3$&$v_1 = 25$&1&0&0&0&25&25&25&25\\
$w_1 = 2$&$v_1 = 20$&2&0&0&20&25&25&45&45\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

This produces a table that looks like this:

[image: Result]

I know my MWE isn't complete, but I included the necessary code to demonstrate the problems with my current table.

Comment: I actually think your version is much nicer. The break lends weight to the header (although perhaps you don't want this).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'd use something like this:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}
\noindent\begin{tabular}{>{$}c<{$}@{,\,}>{$}c<{$}c|ccccccc}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{} & & & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Capacity $j$} \\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{} & $i$ & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
\cline{3-10}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
w_1 = 3 & v_1 = 25 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 25 & 25 & 25 & 25 \\
w_1 = 2 & v_1 = 20 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 20 & 25 & 25 & 45 & 45 \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

1. I didn't used the `booktabs` package, since it doesn't cooperate with vertical lines.
2. I used the `>{...}`, `<{...}` constructs provided by the [array](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/array) package to facilitate the inclusion of math mode for the first and second columns.
3. I used the `@{...}` construct to automatically include the comma between the first and the second columns.
4. I used `\multicolumn` to override the format specification for some columns.
5. I used `\cline{i-j}` (the equivalent in `booktabs` is `\cmidrule`) to obtain a horizontal line spanning from column `i` to column `j`.
6. `\extrarowheight` was used to increase the vertical space of rows; to keep this setting local, you can enclose the code inside braces or inside other construct forming a group (for example a `table` environment,in which case `\noindent` will be superfluous).

Comment: Excellent answer, and with explanations to boot. Thank you.