# How to draw a Cayley table

Tags: tables

I'm trying to make a Cayley table like the one in the following [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52307/how-can-i-make-a-table-like-the-type-in-this-image-in-latex?rq=1), but I don't want the labels, for example, on top (Capacity) and on the left side (the w's and v's). I just would like to reproduce the exact same table without the 'extra' bits on the side.

I forgot to mention I want a 5x5 table (25 entries inside the table), but still with the "outer" headings.

I managed to do this. However, this is long-winded I think:

```
\[
    \begin{tabular}{>{$}l<{$}|*{6}{>{$}l<{$}}}
    ~   & 1   & a   & a^2 & a^3   & a^4     \\
    \hline\vrule height 12pt width 0pt
    1   & 1   & a   & a^2 & a^3  & a^4      \\
    a   & a   & a^2 & a^3 & a^4  & a^5      \\
    a^2 & a^2 & a^3 & a^4 & a^5  & a^6      \\
    a^3 & a^3 & a^4 & a^5 & a^6  & a^7      \\
    a^4 & a^4 & a^5 & a^6 & a^7  & a^8      \\
    \end{tabular}
\]
```

***EDIT:***

```
\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}
\noindent\begin{tabular}{c | c c c c c}

 & 1 & a & a^2 & a^3 & a^4  \\
\cline{1-6}
1   & 1   & a   & a^2 & a^3 & a^4 \\
a   & a   & a^2 & a^3 & a^4 & a^5 \\
a^2 & a^2 & a^3 & a^4 & a^5 & a^6 \\
a^3 & a^3 & a^4 & a^5 & a^6 & a^7 \\
a^4 & a^4 & a^5 & a^6 & a^7 & a^8 \\
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: the answer provided was excellent in the above link, I would appreciate if I can get a similar answer.

Comment: Just take Gonzalo's answer and delete first line (the one which contains `Capacity`) and two left columns and two right ones.

Comment: Welcome!! See this link: [Tables (Overleaf)](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Tables) and then ask if you don't know how to do something.

Comment: @A.E The question you link to was excellent and included a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). We would appreciate if you would ask a similar good question.

Comment: @daniel I am new(I started today) hence I am finding it difficult to start off as I'm just getting used to the stuff

Comment: `array`, not `tabular`.

Comment: You Need to put $a^2$ when you want to use math!

Comment: @A.E As it is, the added code produces tons of errors.

Comment: im going to grab something to eat, then ill be back shortly

Comment: Just take a look to my new answer, you'll understand what you need.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Basically I've just taken the [answer to the question you linked](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52307/how-can-i-make-a-table-like-the-type-in-this-image-in-latex?rq=1) and changed few lines to adapt to your needs.

Here's the code, followed by the output you will get and a brief explanation of what's going on.

The code below produces 2 tables, in one there's written `ANYTHING` in the top left corner, in the second one there's a white space (just don't put anything in the column "argument".

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

    \setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}
\noindent\begin{tabular}{c | c c c c c}
    ANYTHING & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4  \\
    \cline{1-6}
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    1 & 0 & 0 & $a^2$ & 25 & 25 \\
    2 & $a^2$ & 0 & 20 & 25 & 25 \\
    2 & 0 & $a^2$ & 20 & 25 & 25 \\
    2 & 0 & 0 & 20 & 25 & 25 \\
\end{tabular}


\noindent\begin{tabular}{c | c c c c c}
     & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4  \\
    \cline{1-6}
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    1 & 0 & 0 & $a^2$ & 25 & 25 \\
    2 & $a^2$ & 0 & 20 & 25 & 25 \\
    2 & 0 & $a^2$ & 20 & 25 & 25 \\
    2 & 0 & 0 & 20 & 25 & 25 \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

How does it work? A table is done with the environment `{tabular}`, which requires as argument the numer of columns (or rows... just read the documentation to know more) which is specified by the argument `{c | c c c c c}`: 6 columns divided by a line between the first and the second col. The 'c' stands for *centered* meaning that the column will be aligned to the center, if you want you can change it to `l` (left) or `r` (right).

Then in the tables all the entries are done by spacing them with `&`, and the `\cline` takes as argument the number of columns that you want it to span: from column 1 to column 6.

The command `\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}` adds some extra row height (how surprising!).

Package `{array}` is needed for the length `\extrarowheight`.

Comment: this is good however I wanted a 5x5 table

Comment: Cheers pal, much appreciated.

Comment: if you could briefly explain what you did line by line, It would be more beneficial so I know what you've done

Comment: much appreciated

Comment: I added more on the meaning of the `c`'s in `{tabular}` environment.

Comment: understood. however I am getting some issues, ill put it in the edit in the question. so I don't want the "I" as it is a Multiplicative Cayley table but this is giving me errors.

Comment: You can substitute the `i` with everything you want, as all the other entries :)

Comment: I mean, I want that top left corner to be left blank

Comment: So just remove the i in the code where there is $i$ and left it white  :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85655/discussion-between-a-e-and-giutex).

Answer (score 12):

Your input is almost good, but you can do better.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

This is a Cayley table
\[
    \begin{array}{l|*{5}{l}}
        & 1   & a   & a^2 & a^3  & a^4 \\
    \hline
    1   & 1   & a   & a^2 & a^3  & a^4 \\
    a   & a   & a^2 & a^3 & a^4  & a^5 \\
    a^2 & a^2 & a^3 & a^4 & a^5  & a^6 \\
    a^3 & a^3 & a^4 & a^5 & a^6  & a^7 \\
    a^4 & a^4 & a^5 & a^6 & a^7  & a^8 \\
    \end{array} 
\]

This is the same, but with some more spacing,
\[
    \setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt}% local setting
    \begin{array}{l|*{5}{l}}
        & 1   & a   & a^2 & a^3  & a^4 \\
    \hline
    1   & 1   & a   & a^2 & a^3  & a^4 \\
    a   & a   & a^2 & a^3 & a^4  & a^5 \\
    a^2 & a^2 & a^3 & a^4 & a^5  & a^6 \\
    a^3 & a^3 & a^4 & a^5 & a^6  & a^7 \\
    a^4 & a^4 & a^5 & a^6 & a^7  & a^8 \\
    \end{array} 
\]

\end{document}
```

With `array`, each cell is assumed to be in math mode. The setting of `\extrarowheight` will not propagate to other instances of `array`, because `\[...\]` forms a group.

[image]

Comment: I prefer the method above as it is easier to follow(in my eyes anyway) but thanks for your answer

Comment: What does `*` in `l|*` mean?

Comment: @manooooh `*{6}{l}` is short for `llllll`

Comment: @manooooh The `*` refers to the following: `*{6}{l}` means “repeat `l` six times”.

Comment: @jfbu Right, fixed

Answer (score 10):

Some automatizing is in order here

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{xinttools}
\usepackage{bnumexpr}
\begin{document}

This is a Cayley table
\[
    \begin{array}{l|*{5}{l}}
        & 1   & a   & a^2 & a^3  & a^4 \\
    \hline
    1   & 1   & a   & a^2 & a^3  & a^4 \\
    a   & a   & a^2 & a^3 & a^4  & a^5 \\
    a^2 & a^2 & a^3 & a^4 & a^5  & a^6 \\
    a^3 & a^3 & a^4 & a^5 & a^6  & a^7 \\
    a^4 & a^4 & a^5 & a^6 & a^7  & a^8 \\
    \end{array} 
\]

This is the same, but with some more spacing,
\[
    \setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt}% local setting
    \begin{array}{l|*{5}{l}}
        & 1   & a   & a^2 & a^3  & a^4 \\
    \hline
    1   & 1   & a   & a^2 & a^3  & a^4 \\
    a   & a   & a^2 & a^3 & a^4  & a^5 \\
    a^2 & a^2 & a^3 & a^4 & a^5  & a^6 \\
    a^3 & a^3 & a^4 & a^5 & a^6  & a^7 \\
    a^4 & a^4 & a^5 & a^6 & a^7  & a^8 \\
    \end{array} 
\]

Again, but illustrating that $a=4$ generates a cyclic sub-group of order
$5$ of $(\mathbb{Z}/11\mathbb{Z})^*$:
\[
    \setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt}% local setting
    \begin{array}{c|*{5}{c}}
        & 1   & a   & a^2 & a^3  & a^4 \\
    \hline
    \xintFor #1 in {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}:
    {\ifnum #1=0 1\else a^{#1}\fi 
       \xintFor #2 in {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}:
      {%
       &\thebnumexpr 4^(#1+#2) /: 11\relax
      }%
    \\
    }%
    \end{array} 
\]
and $a=2$ generates the full group:
\[
    \setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt}% local setting
    \begin{array}{c|*{10}{c}}
        & 1 & a  \xintFor*#1 in {23456789}:{&a^{#1}}\\
    \hline
    \xintFor* #1 in {0123456789}:
    {\ifnum #1=0 1\else a^{#1}\fi 
       \xintFor* #2 in {0123456789}:
      {%
       &\thebnumexpr 2^(#1+#2) /: 11\relax
      }%
    \\
    }%
    \end{array} 
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 I'm always amazed at how efficient `xinttools` is!

Comment: @Andrew your expl3 answer does look efficient too `:)`

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps I over automate, but I'd want to have a macro `\CayleyTable` that produces the Cayley table of the corresponding cyclic group, so that the commands:

```
  \CayleyTable{3}
  \CayleyTable{4}
  \CayleyTable[x]{9}
```

would produce:

[image]

(An optional argument gives the name of the generator, which defaults to `a`). Arguably, `\CyclicGroupCayleyTable` would be a better name. In any case, 
here's the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt}% local setting

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_new:N \l_n_int
\tl_new:N  \l_gen_tl
\cs_new_protected:Npn \print_exponent #1 {%  {\l_gen_tl}^{#1}
  \int_compare:nTF {#1=0}{1}{\l_gen_tl \int_compare:nT{#1>1}{^{#1}}}
}
\cs_new_protected:Npn \print_Cayley_header:n #1 { 
    & \print_exponent {\int_eval:n{#1-1}} 
}
\cs_new_protected:Npn \print_Cayley_cell:nn #1 #2 {
    & \print_exponent {\int_eval:n { \int_mod:nn {#1+#2-2}{\l_n_int}} }
}
\cs_new_protected:Npn \print_Cayley_row:n #1 {
  \print_exponent {\int_eval:n {#1-1}}
  \int_step_inline:nn {\l_n_int} {\print_Cayley_cell:nn {##1}{#1}} \\
}
\NewDocumentCommand\CayleyTable{ O{a} m}{
   \tl_set:Nn \l_gen_tl {#1}
   \int_set:Nn \l_n_int {#2}
   \[
      \begin{array}{c|*{\int_eval:n{\l_n_int+1}}{c}}
        \int_step_function:nN {\l_n_int} \print_Cayley_header:n
        \\\hline
        \int_step_function:nN {\l_n_int} \print_Cayley_row:n
      \end{array}
   \]
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

  \CayleyTable{3}

  \CayleyTable{4}

  \CayleyTable[x]{9}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

With `\foreach`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{mynode/.style={anchor=base,  
    inner sep=0pt,
    text height=12pt, text depth=6pt, text width=18pt, text centered}}
\newcommand{\CayleyTable}[2][a]{%
\vcenter{\hbox{\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro\tot{int(#2-1)}
\foreach \i in {0,1,...,\tot}
{
\node[mynode] (hh-\i) at (\i *24pt,24pt) {\ifnumequal{\i}{0}{$1$}{\ifnumequal{\i}{1}{$#1$}{${#1}^{\i}$}}};
\node[mynode] (vv-\i) at (-24pt-\pgflinewidth,-\i *24pt) {\ifnumequal{\i}{0}{$1$}{\ifnumequal{\i}{1}{$#1$}{${#1}^{\i}$}}};
}
\foreach \myrow in {0,1,...,\tot} 
{\foreach \mycol in {0,1,...,\tot} 
{\pgfmathsetmacro\myplus{\myrow+\mycol}\pgfmathsetmacro\myexp{int(mod(\myplus,#2))}
\node[mynode] at (\myrow*24pt,-\mycol*24pt) {\ifnumequal{\myexp}{0}{$1$}{\ifnumequal{\myexp}{1}{$#1$}{${#1}^{\myexp}$}}};}}
\draw ([yshift=-2pt]hh-\tot.south east) -- ([yshift=-2pt]hh-0.south west) -- ++(-24pt, 0);
\draw ([xshift=2pt]vv-\tot.south east) -- ([xshift=2pt]vv-0.north east) -- ++(0,24pt);
\end{tikzpicture}}}%
}
\begin{document}
\[
  \CayleyTable{3}
 \]
 \[
  \CayleyTable[x]{4}
 \]
 \[
  \CayleyTable[y]{5}
\]
 \end{document}
```

[image]