# How to make two tables side by side?

Tags: tables

I would like to design two Cayley tables as given in the image below. Till now I am only able to do this much see the code

```
\begin{table}[]


  \begin{tabular}{llll}


 * & a & b & c \\
  & c & a & b \\
 & a & b & c \\
 & b & c & a
 \end{tabular}
  \end{table}
```

[image]

Question : How to make the diagrams given in image?

Comment: Do you want to add a caption to tha tables? If yes, do you want an individual caption for each of them (table 1 and table 2)  or do you want two subcaprions and a common cpation (table 1a and table1b)?

Comment: Is your question just about the side-by-side position of two tables or also about the contents of the table itself? Could you please clarify?

Comment: [How can I have two tables side by side?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2832/134144) might be worth having a look at. Maybe you are also interested in [How to draw a Cayley table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/459639/134144)